# Prestashop: How to get virtual product in the cart for use in Address.php?

Tags: php, prestashop, virtual, required

In Prestashop CMS, *address1* is only required if there is a virtual product in the cart.

How can this be achieved? Does anybody have the solution for this?

Comment: Can you share what you've tried so far?

Comment: brijmcq, thanks for your reply, I did it already.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$context = Context::getContext();
$cart = $context->cart;
$is_virtual = $cart->isVirtualCart();
```

Works perfectly. Example:

```
        if (in_array('address1', $arr) && $is_virtual) {
            $this->def['fields']['address1']['required'] = 0;
        } else if (in_array('address1', $arr)) {
            $this->def['fields']['address1']['required'] = 1;
            $this->fieldsRequired[] = 'address1';
        } else {
            $this->def['fields']['address1']['required'] = 0;
        }
```